# AndroidとPCの通信

Tags: android, java

AndroidとPCでStringやCharなどの文字列をUSBやBluetoothなどを使って転送することはできるのでしょうか。
いろいろ調べてみて、試してみたのですがうまくいかなかったので質問させていただきたいと思います。 
AndroidもPCもJavaで書きたいと思っています。あと、この場合WindowsとMacでは同じコードで動くのでしょうか。
 私はMacを使って開発をしているのですが、もしかして原因はそれかとも思っています。

Comment: 単に通信出来れば良いだけなら、例えばWiFiで同一ネットワークにAndroid端末とPCをつないで、TCP/IP通信を行うという方式があります。もう少し具体的な状況（やりたいこと）を追記されると、欲しい回答がつくかもしれません。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
TCP/IPの手段がありましたか！思いつかなかったです。
なんとかTCP/IPで解決できました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

回答するのを忘れていました。

yohjpさんのコメントのおかげで、無事解決することが出来ました。
ありがとうございました。